# Inserting String Array Elements into a List

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array, polymorphism, user-defined-data-types

I want to create an array list of Owners and their properties using a 2D string data array that has been provided. I don't know how to convert the strings in order to make them into a list of owners. I need to first check to see if the owner list is empty and if so add the owners name to the list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class PropertyTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean present = true;
    ArrayList <Owner> ownerList = new ArrayList <Owner>();

    String dataArray[][] = {{"Jones","Commercial","123 Mitchell","Arlington","Texas","76019","120000", "sales", "21000"},
                            {"Smith","Residential","61 Bose Lane","Dallas","Texas","75002","310000", "65656"},
                            {"Jones","Commercial","2500 West Seventh St"," Fort Worth","Texas","76015","575000","food", "15750"},
                            {"Smith","Commercial","1225 Green Rd","Euless","Texas","76000","215500","entertainment","9500"},
                            {"Jones","Residential","5214 Linda Lane","Houston","Texas","77700","195775", "98541"}};
```

Comment: Do you have a class named `Owner`?

Answer (score 1):

This code will help you to get the correct output.
If i take this string array as example:java

```
public <T> List<T> twoDArrayStringToList(T[][] dataArray) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T[] array : dataArray) {
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));
    }
    return list;
}
public static void main(String args[]){

     String dataArray[][] = {{"Jones","Commercial","123 Mitchell","Arlington","Texas","76019","120000", "sales", "21000"},
             {"Smith","Residential","61 Bose Lane","Dallas","Texas","75002","310000", "65656"},
             {"Jones","Commercial","2500 West Seventh St"," Fort Worth","Texas","76015","575000","food", "15750"},
             {"Smith","Commercial","1225 Green Rd","Euless","Texas","76000","215500","entertainment","9500"},
             {"Jones","Residential","5214 Linda Lane","Houston","Texas","77700","195775", "98541"}};

     System.out.println(twoDArrayStringToList(dataArray));

}
```

[Jones, Commercial, 123 Mitchell, Arlington, Texas, 76019, 120000, sales, 21000, Smith, Residential, 61 Bose Lane, Dallas, Texas, 75002, 310000, 65656, Jones, Commercial, 2500 West Seventh St,  Fort Worth, Texas, 76015, 575000, food, 15750, Smith, Commercial, 1225 Green Rd, Euless, Texas, 76000, 215500, entertainment, 9500, Jones, Residential, 5214 Linda Lane, Houston, Texas, 77700, 195775, 98541]

Answer (score 0):

i believe this function can help you

```
 public String[] addString (String[] a , String c){

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (a == null){

        list.add(c);

        String[] b = new String[list.size()];

        for (int j = 0 ; j<list.size() ; j++){
            b[j] = list.get(j);
        }
        return b;

    }else {
        for (int i = 0 ; i<a.length ; i++) {
            list.add(a[i]);
        }
        list.add(c);

        String[] b = new String[list.size()];

        for (int j = 0 ; j<list.size() ; j++){
            b[j] = list.get(j);
        }

        return b;

    }



}
```

use for() for adding your array